# LeetCode: An unknown error occurred. Please try again later, or contact us if this issue persists

Tags: linux, firefox

(Not a bad title - that is literally what the error is and this is likely what any future person that encounters the issue will search for)

Browser used: Firefox 90.0.2 (Ubuntu x86_64)

After clicking on the `Submit` button on LeetCode for a solution, the following message popped up in the red in the bottom-right corner:

[image]
"An unknown error occurred. Please try again later, or contact us if this problem persists."

What could be causing this? I've tried to enable all cookies and it doesn't change anything. (Self-answered below.)

Answer (score 0):

## Short Solution:

Set `network.http.sendRefererHeader` to 2.

## Explanation of why the solution is what it is:

The core issue here is the `Referer` header that is sent with each request. It is okay to only send `Referer` header when primary domain matches (referer header from *a.example.com* to *b.example.com* is allowed, but not to *b.otherwebsite.com*).
However, in Firefox (as of 90.0.4 Linux x64), there is a setting `network.http.sendRefererHeader` which was set to `1` (by me, it defaults to 2), which restricts `Referer` headers to be only sent when clicking on links, buttons and such, regardless of the origin policy you've set.

LeetCode relies on the `Referer` header to be sent with all requests to their subdomains, regardless of whether it is for an image, a custom UI component, or an XHR request, doesn't matter. So, when clicking on the `Submit` button, since it's a custom UI component (not the HTML button), the browser doesn't recognise it as a form button, and doesn't send the `Referer` header with it. The LeetCode servers think that this is a bot request, or someone requesting the component directly without being on the previous page, and subsequently rejects it. So, set that configuration to `2`.